# How to pass data by using an AJAX request to app.post() method in Express?

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, express

I develop a blog application using express and node, and I need to pass an array of keywords to the app.post() method to save a blog post (no database is used, an array holds these blog posts) with its keywords.

**First, I have implemented a script to display keywords as separate  elements:**

```
$("#keywordInput").on("keydown", function(event) {
        // "13" corresponds to the "Enter" key
        if (event.which === 13) {
            const maxKeywords = 6;

            // The input element will not accept any input
            event.preventDefault(); 
            
            const keyword = $(this).val().trim();

            if(keyword !== "") {
                if ($('#keywordList .keyword').length < maxKeywords) {
                    const keywordTag = $('<span>').addClass('keyword').text(keyword);
    
                    $('#keywordList').append(keywordTag);
                    $(this).val(''); 
                }
                else {
                    alert("You have entered too many keywords.");
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Then, another script reads their text and pushes them to an array:**

```
$('.submitBtn').on("click", () => {
        var keywordArray = []
        $('.keyword').each(function() {
            keywordArray.push($(this).text());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/submit", 
            data: JSON.stringify({ keywords: keywordArray }), 
        });
    })
```

**And here is my app.post() function:**

```
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
    const newTitle = req.body['postTitle'];
    const titleExists = post_array.some(post => post.title === newTitle);
    if (titleExists) {
        res.render("partials/return.ejs");
    }
    else {
        const post = {
            keywords: req.body.keywords,
            title: req.body['postTitle'],
            content: req.body['postContent'],
            authors: req.body['postAuthor'],
            date: formattedDate,
        }
        post_array.push(post);
        const selectedPost = post_array[0];
        const data = {
            posts: post_array,
            selectedPost: selectedPost,
        }
        res.render("partials/viewPosts.ejs", data);
    }
});
```

It seems that "req.body.keywords" **returns "undefined"**, I don't really know much about how to use $.ajax() method so any idea is appreciated to pass the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two types of request: JSON and URL-encoded.

It's being sent as default type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), so it's not being parsed correctly by JSON parser on express server, or url-encoded parser.

So, you can send it as URL-encoded, in which case you don't need to stringify object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/submit",
    data: { keywords: keywordArray },
});
```

*Note that you need to setup [url-encoded parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) on express server*

Or, if you wish to send it as a JSON request, you need to explicitly set JSON content-type, along with stringifying object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/submit",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ keywords: keywordArray }),
});
```

See [jQuery ajax request docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the correction. When I try to pass the data as JSON request, I get undefined. So, I have tried your first suggestion to pass it as URL-encoded. Now, I get this output for "req.body.keywords": [array of my keywords] undefined So, I get both the array and "undefined" and the array is not displayed on my web page. How should I call the array inside of my ".ejs" file?

Comment: well, that seems that on express you have url-encoded middleware, which is working, but not json.. for json request, make sure you use json parser: `app.use(express.json())`, (or you can keep using the url-encoded, just don't mix them). as to the output, it seems that keywords are correctly parsed, but something else is undefined. in your post request, you send only keywords, and on the server you read other properties from req.body, so, you need to include other properties to the request that are required on the server (`postTitle`, `postContent` etc.),, and then pass them to ejs

Comment: on the ejs view, to loop an array, try then `<% posts.forEach(post=>...`